# Compute $\int_0^2\frac {\arctan{x}}{x^2+2x+2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> Compute $I=\int_0^2\frac {\arctan{x}}{x^2+2x+2}dx$

My 2 attempts:

First:

We observe that $\frac {1}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac {1}{(x+1)^2+1}$ and $\frac 1{(x+1)^2+1}=(\arctan{(x+1)})^{'}.$ Then:

$$\int_0^2\frac{\arctan{x}}{x^2+2x+2}dx=\int_0^2\arctan{x}(\arctan{(x+1)})^{'}dx=\left.\arctan{x}\arctan{(x+1)}\right|_0^2-\int_0^2\frac{1\times\arctan{(x+1)}}{1+x^2}dx=\left.\arctan{x}\arctan{(x+1)}\right|_0^2-\int_0^2\frac{(1+x^2-x^2)\times\arctan{(x+1)}}{1+x^2}dx=\left.\arctan{x}\arctan{(x+1)}\right|_0^2-\int_0^2\arctan{(x+1)}dx-\int_0^2\frac{x^2\arctan{(x+1)}}{1+x^2}dx$$

Where the second integral is pretty easy to solve using integration by parts but the second one is not very pleasant so... I thought I should try something else.

Second attempt:

Let $u=\arctan(x+1)$ then $x=\tan u-1$ then $$I=\int_{\arctan1}^{arctan3}\arctan{(\tan u -1)du}$$

then I could let $w=\tan(u)-1$ then $dw=((w+1)^2+1)du$... but it's a lot of work and I really think you can do this more easily...

Any hints?

Comment: Your first derivative is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah, my bad. it's the other way around. I just edited it, but it's easily to be seen that I mean that the derivative of the *right-hand side* since on the next line I wrote that.

Comment: Maybe partial fractions could help since $$\frac{1}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac{i}{2 (x+(1+i))}-\frac{i}{2 (x+(1-i))}.$$ Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

***Some thoughts here:***

\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{\arctan x dx}{(x+1)^2+1}\\
&=\int\frac{\arctan (u-1) du}{u^2+1}\\
&=\int\frac{\arctan(\tan w-1)\sec^2w dw}{\sec^2w}\\
&=\int\arctan(\tan w-1)dw
\end{align}

Using similar substitutions, consider
$$J=\int\frac{\text{arccot} x dx}{(x+1)^2+1}=\int\text{arccot}(\tan w-1)dw$$

Notice
$$\arctan x+\text{arccot}x=\frac\pi 2$$

So
$$I+J=\frac{\pi}{2}\int^2_0\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2+1}=\frac{\pi}2(\arctan3-\frac{\pi}4)$$

Comment: Yeah, but to calculate $I$ you should know $I-J$ too. So then you'll get $\arctan(\tan w-1)-\arctan(\frac 1{\tan w-1})=\arctan{\frac {\tan w-1-\frac 1{\tan w-1}}{2}}$ and to integrate that idk....